# Complex SQL Query Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I want make a query to mysql database that gets me the products that are available, have **sale_id of anything1 or anything2 or both** and belong to categories of **Ids a or b or both from table category_product** which has **(category_product table)** 2 columns **product_id and category_id** since my products can belong to multiple categories.

**HERE IS MY QUERY:**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products 
 WHERE available = 1 
   AND sale_id = 3 
    OR sale_id = 4 
   AND id IN (
   SELECT product_id 
     FROM category_product 
    WHERE category_id = 2 
       OR category_id = 3
)
```

But It didn't work!!!

The Result was that it got the first query correct the one with available = 1 and sale_id = 3 or 4 or both.. But the products it got didn't belong to categories 2 or 3 or both

Any Help Please!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need parentheses or `IN`:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p
WHERE p.available = 1 AND
      p.sale_id IN (3, 4) AND
      p.id IN (SELECT product_id 
               FROM category_product cp
               WHERE category_id IN (2, 3)
              );
```

You seem to be learning SQL -- or at least boolean expressions.  `AND` and `OR` don't automatically do what you want.  When you are mixing them, use parentheses until you get the hang of it.

Your condition parses as:

```
WHERE (p.available = 1 AND p.sale_id = 3) OR
      (p.sale_id = 4 AND
       p.id IN (SELECT product_id 
                FROM category_product cp
                WHERE category_id IN (2, 3)
               )
      )
```

Comment: IT WORK THANKS you just need to add (AND) after `p.sale_id IN (3, 4)`. I cant seem to edit it. Thanks